# Business Intelligence integration in .NET MVC project

Tags: c#, data-visualization, business-intelligence, asp.net, mvc

What are good solutions (open or not, free or not) to **integrate a business intelligence solution into an existing .NET MVC project?** I would like to provide to the end user tool to aggregate and analyze data with more with the utmost flexibility and usability possible.

I was thinking on Microsoft **PowerBi**.

Answer (score 1):

[Syncfusion Dashboard](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/dashboard) is an end to end Dashboard and Business Intelligence solution.

Dashboards can be deployed with the dashboard server or embedded in your web application. 
([details](https://help.syncfusion.com/dashboard-platform/dashboard-sdk/getting-started/aspnet-mvc))

[image: Syncfusion Dashboard]

The Dashboard Platform available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue) and flat licensing is available even otherwise (not counting the number of users).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.